# Force Main DIV Containing Image DIVs to Float Center

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm having a difficult time forcing a DIV which contains a group of images each wrapped in a DIV, to center within my responsive element. I've tried to provide width of 100% to the main DIV, and use both a mix of clear and float on the image DIVs, but I cannot seem to get them to budge at all. I know I'm close, but cannot find what I'm missing. Here's what I have:

```
<footer>
   <div id="Follow-Us"><p>Follow us on:</p></div>

   <div id="social">           
       <!--<div id="left-social-spacer"></div>-->
            <div id="FB">
                <img src="Images/FB.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div id="Tweet" style="margin: 0 auto">
                <img src="Images/Twitter.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div id="WP" style="margin: 0 auto">
                <img src="Images/WordPress.jpg" />
            </div>                         
   </div><!-- end social -->
</footer>
<div id="safety"></div>
</article>

<hr />
<div id="Unsubscribe"><p>Not interested in email updates? <a href="mailtocontent" target="_blank">Unsubscribe here</a>. Click <a href="http://www.content.com/">here</a> to subscribe.
 <br /><br />To ensure that subscription newsletters make it to your inbox, add <a href="mailtocontent"><!--info@content.com--></a> to your address book.</p>

</div>
```

This is what it looks like at runtime in both normal and responsive design:

[image]
[image]

And here's my controlling CSS for it:

```
#FB 
{
    float: right;    
    /*position: relative;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

#Tweet 
{
    float: left;
    /*position: relative;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: fuchsia;
}

#WP 
{
    float: left;
    /*position: relative;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: hotpink;
}

#social div 
{                 
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 57px;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
}

#left-social-spacer 
{
    width:90%;    
    /*background-color: #ff0000;*/
    height: 37px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 59px;    
}

footer 
{
    /*background-color: #003E79;*/
    height: 37px;
    display: block;
}

#Follow-Us p 
{
    clear: left; 
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#LowNavBar p 
{
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#Copyright p 
{
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -15px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#safety 
{
    clear: both;
    /*background-color: #ee7799;*/
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 50px;*/
}

.no_anchor_styles 
{
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#read-more 
{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

What am I missing here, or what am I adding in that shouldn't be here that's keeping me from controlling the DIVs to force them to the center?

Comment: Why are you using float:left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are the changes, you have to make in your codes to align `footer` with `social` in center.

```
#FB 
{
    float: left; /*Float towards left not right*/   
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

#social 
{                 
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 57px;    
    margin: 0 15px;
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    width:60px;
}

footer 
{
    /*background-color: #003E79;*/
    height: 110px;
    display: block;
    width:90px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`text-align-center` the parent and `display:inline-block` the social icons.

Example:

```css
.main {
  text-align: center;
}
.in {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="in">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
  </div>
  <div class="in">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
  </div>
</div>
```